# rename object created <-as.character

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
dune.spec<-data.frame(Species=colnames(dune))
species<-as.character(dune.spec$Species)


levels(species)[levels(species)=="Achimill"] <- "test"
library(dplyr)
species<-rename(species, replace = c("Achimill" = "test"))
```

I'd like to rename a specific name. For example "Achimill" to "test". Seems like such a simple thing to do but I can't find a method that works. Neither levels of rename function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
dune.spec = data.frame(Species = colnames(dune))
species = as.character(dune.spec$Species)
```

`species` is `character`, that's why you can't get `levels` to work, as it operates on `factor`

```
class(species)
#[1] "character"
```

Substitute the way you want using methods available for `character`, such as `base::gsub`

```
species = gsub("Achimill", "test", species)
```

---

Alternatively, since it seems you may actually be trying to use the factors, operate on a factor using appropriate methods

```
dune.spec$Species = factor(dune.spec$Species, labels = gsub("Achimill", "test", levels(dune.spec$Species)))
dune.spec$Species
# [1] test     Agrostol Airaprae Alopgeni Anthodor Bellpere Bromhord Chenalbu
# [9] Cirsarve Comapalu Eleopalu Elymrepe Empenigr Hyporadi Juncarti Juncbufo
#[17] Lolipere Planlanc Poaprat  Poatriv  Ranuflam Rumeacet Sagiproc Salirepe
#[25] Scorautu Trifprat Trifrepe Vicilath Bracruta Callcusp
#30 Levels: test Agrostol Airaprae Alopgeni Anthodor Bellpere ... Vicilath
```

Comment: gsub it is. Thanks.